# Fabric Plugin is not getting install in android studio 1.5 on linux system

Tags: android, android-studio, twitter-fabric

I have Linux system with android studio ver-1.5. I am trying to download plug-in for Fabric. Plugin is downloaded successfully but zip file is not getting unzipped and showing as corrupted.

Please let me know how can I download plugin zip out side of the android studio and link with android studio. I tried to find fabric plugin download link but I could not find it.

Thanks,
Silvans

Comment: fabric plugin download link https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/8002-fabric-for-android-studio

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Follow Below simple step..

1. Download android studio plugin from [fabric plugin download link](http://plugins.jetbrains.com/files/8002/22275/FabricAndroidStudioPlugin.zip).
2. Go to File>Setting>Plugin>Install Plugin from Disk.
3. Select Downloded Zip file.
4. Restart Android studio and you are done.

**EDIT:**

You can see list of released plugins on following link and can download latest version:

[Fabric for Android Studio](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/idea/plugin/8002-fabric-for-android-studio)

Comment: Thanks for providing link to download plugin, i was only unable to find this link to download.